# Is the second city available on BMC for android

Tags: android, bloons-monkey-city

I am playing Bloons Monkey City on Android. Various forums etc mention a second city but I can't figure out how to get to it or how it works. I am high level and have build almost all buildings and researched almost all technologies.

Is the second city a feature on the Android version? If so how do I access it?

Answer (score 2):

No.  There is no way to get the second city on mobile.  However, you can unlock engineers by beating the special mission.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to get the second city in BMC mobile at this point.  They added this to the web version alongside Monkey Engineers, which are available on the mobile version already.

There's [talk on the forums from a NinjaKiwi staffer](http://ninjakiwi.com/forums/214-bloons-monkey-city-mobile/posts/58449-second-city-for-mobile) that they might consider it at some point, but there doesn't appear to be any plans in the near term.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that it is and you have to have the first city at level 15+. Other than that, there's not much to find about this.

Is your first city at level 15+?

[Source: Wiki](http://bloons.wikia.com/wiki/Bloon_Dunes_(Bloons_Monkey_City))

Comment: My city is level 32. This isn't really an answer.